# Installation on MacOS fails for Stephen Diehl's "Implementing a JIT compiled language with Haskell and LLVM"

Tags: haskell, build, compiler-construction, llvm

having trouble setting up [Stephen Diehl's Haskell + LLVM project](https://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/) on Mac OS (latest).  I have tried:

1. The given instructions, which start with `brew install llvm-hs/homebrew-llvm/llvm-4.0`.  This command actually downloads 4.0.1.  The build fails with [many errors](https://gist.github.com/jxxcarlson/892cc390d083c5df02ceed3bbde918cd).
2. I then tried `brew install llvm-hs/llvm/llvm-9`.  This install succeeded, but then `stack build` failed.  I was able to fix one set of errors by installing a library that defined the `IEEE` type, but this produced additoinal errors.  And so on.
3. List item